# ComponentDidMount causing my server to crash

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-state-management

Below is my Code. ComponentDidMount lifecycle method is invoking on a function which is further making a fetch call to the server. The problem is infinite fetch calls are being made to the server.

Can someone explain what could be going wrong. If I do not use ComponentDidMount lifecycle method and invoke the function (making fetch request) then everything seems to be working fine.

```
class BusinessList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getBusinessList();
    }

    render() {
        if (!cookie.load('userservice')) return <Redirect to="/"/>
        else {
            this.props.resetLoginForm();
            if (this.props.businessList.length === 0) {
                // No business Configured. Display the option to add new business
                return <div>No Business Configured. Add a new Business</div>
            }
            else if (this.props.businessList[0]['message']) {
                //message is present in BusinessList state i.e. an error so just display the message
                return <div>{this.props.businessList[0].message}</div>
            }
            else {
                // data is present. Display the data. ALong with option to Add New Business.
                return <BusinessCard businessList={this.props.businessList}/>
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Need the code for `getBusinessList `

Comment: export const getBusinessList = function (dispatch) {
    return fetch(baseUrl + 'business', {
        credentials : "include"
    })
    .then ((response) => response.json())
    .then ((dataObject) => {
        console.log(dataObject);
        dispatch(businessList(dataObject));
    })

}
// It is updating the redux store after getting a fetch request. And this is being invoked from the MainComponent, which in return is passing dispatch function as argument.

Comment: It is running in a cycle you call `getBusinessList ` in `componentDidMount`  this function forces the component to mount again and then again it calls itself in `componentDidMount`. It's a cyclic infinite process.

Comment: Yes. I will explain whats happening. componentDidMount is invoking a function which is making a fetch request to the server, upon receiving response it is updating the redux store (which has the state for BusinessList). Now every time component is rendered, componentDidmount method is being called, which in turn is making a fetch request, which in turn is updating the state in redux store, which in turn is causing the render to be executed, which in turn is causing the componentDidMount function to be executed again. --- This is causing infinite loop. What is the solution to this?

Comment: Solution to is that the parameters that this component is consuming need to be passed as props and handled inside the component. Once the api call fetches the props will get updated rather than whole component getting re rendered. So in short you need to change the flow where component will re-render such that props from api call are passed inside it. Does that make sense ?

Comment: The parameters (i.e. the state and any necessary functions ) is already being passed as props.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with render function, whenever `resetLoginForm` is called your components gets rerendered which is causing the infinite loop. Move this function to `componentDidMount` as well:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getBusinessList();
  if(cookie.load('userservice')) {
    this.props.resetLoginForm();
  }
}
```

Comment: Done. Still doesnt work. I will explain whats happening. componentDidMount is invoking a function which is making a fetch request to the server, upon receiving response it is updating the redux store (which has  the state for BusinessList). Now every time component is rendered, componentDidmount method is being called, which in turn is making a fetch request, which in turn is updating the state in redux store, which in turn is causing the render to be executed, which in turn is causing the componentDidMount function to be executed again. --- This is causing infinite loop.

Comment: Got it, getBusinessList() shouldn't be called here, it should one step up in the hierarchy.

Comment: Like I am redirecting to this page from LoginPage once the user logs in successfully. If I try and fetch the data there, it is still causing infinte loop.

Comment: How are you rendering BusinessList component? Can you paste that code as well.

Comment: Code for BusinessList component is pasted above at Main question - start of the thread. Apart from this anything else ?

Comment: export const getBusinessList = function (dispatch) { return fetch(baseUrl + 'business', { credentials : "include" }) .then ((response) => response.json()) .then ((dataObject) => { console.log(dataObject); dispatch(businessList(dataObject)); }) }

Comment: I'm asking about where you're rendering this component, I mean parent of BusinessList component.

Comment: class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div id="root">
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component = {() => <Login postLoginUser={this.props.postLoginUserDispatcher} loginMessage={this.props.loginMessage} />}/>
                    <Route exact path="/business" component = {() => <BusinessList businessList={this.props.businessList} resetLoginForm={this.props.resetLoginForm} getBusinessList = {this.props.getBusinessList}/>}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Comment: Managed to find the fix. Thankyou for your help and efforts.

Comment: What is the fix? I'm just curious.

Comment: Just implemented the componentDidMount in the parent component. So when ever the states update, iembedded component will be re rendered not the parent component.